# How do i make a command that make my bot leave from the server (discord.py)

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I have a bot I need to add a command .leave that make him leave the server
I have tried some codes but didn't help

```
@client.command()
async def leaveguild(ctx):
    await discord.Guild.leave()
    await ctx.send(f"I'm going , bye!")
```

Comment: what codes have you tried? Please add them to your question

Comment: First of all, edit your question and put the code there, second of all you need `intents.guilds` enabled, third of all I'm not entirely sure how you'd pass a guild in that command

Comment: how to enable intent.guilds?

Comment: It's probably also your first time ever programming. Don't start coding discord bots if you don't have a basic knowledge of python and OOP.

Comment: not on programming on this stack overflow

Comment: You are new to programming, it's really easy to see

Comment: we don't write code for others here, we explain so people you can understand it and solve it yourself. I'm writing an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`discord.Guild` is a **class** not an **instance** ([here's an explanation on what's the difference](https://dev.to/ogwurujohnson/distinguishing-instance-variables-from-class-variables-in-python-81)). You need to get the instance from somewhere, the easiest way would be with `ctx.guild`, (the bot will leave the guild where the command was invoked). The rest of the code was correct.

```py
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.send("I am leaving this guild!")
    await ctx.guild.leave()
```

Comment: oh so I'm wrong i have used discord.guild so i m an noob